# Should images with multiple objects of the same class be used as training sample for multi-classes object detection models?

Tags: training, computer-vision, multiclass-classification, object-detection

Let's say the model try to detect all the grapes on a branch of grapes. Can I use images of a grape branch with all the grapes labeled as a training sample? Will it affect the quality of the RPN ? Is it better to train on images which a single or a few grapes in it, since the classification is done separately on each slide of the image?